# Call template function for each argument of variardic template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to make simple DI with specialized template function, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
T inject();

template<>
int inject() {
    std::cout << "injected int" << std::endl;
    return 123;
}

class Test {
public:
    Test(int arg) {
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename C, typename... Args>
C* instantiate() {
    return new C(inject<Args>()...);
}

int main() {
    auto test = instantiate<Test>();
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, it does not work. Is it possible to deduct variadic `Args` like this and call `instantiate` for each of it, passing result to given type `C` constructor?

Comment: Based on what do you want `Args` to be deduced? Based on the parameter types of the constructor of `C`?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to give such unclear questions and add under an answer more and more details. Please provide a much more clarified question instead of changing the requirements step wise by comments on answers! Thanks!

Comment: Its not something new. All this points specified in original questions as part of code example.

Comment: And yes, they must be deduced from args of C constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

struct injected {
    operator int() const { return 123; }
    operator double() const { return 3.14; }
    operator const char*() const { return "foo"; }
};

template <std::size_t, typename T>
using repeat = T;

template <typename C>
C* instantiate(std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>) {
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename C, std::size_t... Is>
auto instantiate(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<C, repeat<Is, injected>...>{}, C*> {
    return new C((void(Is), injected{})...);
}

template <typename C, std::size_t... Is>
auto instantiate(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> std::enable_if_t<not std::is_constructible<C, repeat<Is, injected>...>{}, C*> {
    return instantiate<C>(std::index_sequence<Is..., sizeof...(Is)>{});
}

template <typename C>
C* instantiate() {
    return instantiate<C>(std::index_sequence<>{});
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d7aaf4dd682cc25)